# Synching yup validation schema with type of File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup

Here's my code:

```
type FormValues = {
  files: File[];
  notify: string[];
};

const validationSchema = yup.object({
  files: yup
    .array<File[]>()
    .of(
      yup
        .mixed<File>()
        .required()
        .test('file', 'Invalid file type', (value) => value instanceof File),
    )
    .min(1, 'At least one file is required')
    .required(),
  notify: yup.array().of(yup.string().required()).required(),
}).required();

export function UploadFileDialog() {
  const methods = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      files: [],
      notify: [],
    },
    resolver: yupResolver<FormValues>(validationSchema),
  });
```

The error

```
TypeScript Error: Argument of type 'RequiredObjectSchema<{
  files: RequiredArraySchema<MixedSchema<File | undefined, AnyObject, File>, AnyObject, (File | undefined)[] | undefined>;
  notify: RequiredArraySchema<...>;
}, AnyObject, TypeOfShape<...>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectSchema<FormValues, AnyObject, TypeOfShape<FormValues>, AssertsShape<FormValues>>'.

The types of 'fields.files' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'RequiredArraySchema<MixedSchema<File | undefined, AnyObject, File>, AnyObject, (File | undefined)[] | undefined>' is missing the following properties from type 'File[]': pop, push, join, reverse, and 33 more.
```

So it seems that `RequiredArraySchema` doesn't actually return an array. Any idea how to get around this issue?

Using InferType just kicks the problem down the road since mixed is `| undefined` by default

```
export declare function create<TType = any>(): MixedSchema<TType | undefined, AnyObject, TType | undefined>;
```

Answer (score 0):

this fixed it...

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  files: yup
    .array()
    .of(
      yup
        .mixed<File>()
        .required()
        .test('file', 'Invalid file type', (value) => value instanceof File),
    )
    .min(1, 'At least one file is required')
    .required(),
  notify: yup.array().of(yup.string().required()).required(),
}).required();
```

Remember to use `object().shape()`